# How do I disable sub-pixel rendering or force the browser to round properties to the nearest pixel?

Tags: css, frontend, styling

My problem as stated in the title is about chrome's sub-pixel rendering. Sometimes you want the browser to determine an element's proper height or width so it takes up all the available space. And that's how floating point values appear. When the numbers after the decimal are high, it seems to get imprecise and make weird spacings. Changing the box-border property doesn't change the result. I made a codepen showing the problem, make sure to use a browser supporting sub-pixel rendering. As you zoom in you can see a space between the border and the pseudo-element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  
  width: 100.98px;
  height: 100px;
  
  margin-left: 2px;
  
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content:'';
  
  width: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  
  right: 0;
  
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
```

Comment: Good question but I don't think there is any way of *forcing* a browser to do something it doesn't want to do, especially cross browser.

Comment: Well, at least a way of rounding the CSS properties without having to hardcode the measures would be nice.

Comment: Facing similar problem in the recent project. **+1**.

Comment: As others have said, I don’t think there is a way of the sort you want. There are workarounds in some situations, eg in your example putting the background on a slightly larger pseudo element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that rounding the width and height doesn't solve the problem at all; it's not about the float values (could be a factor). After some experimenting I found a trick of sorts. If you somehow manage to throw in a `right: -1px` or a `left: -1px` to the element's style it will no longer get weirdly spaced out (right: 0 or 1 doesn't work). I tested it with a resizable element. You can move it back into it's original position with `transform: translateX(-1px)` and there it is. No more subpixel gaps between elements. I made a codepen showcasing the solution: https://codepen.io/m4tex-the-sasster/pen/zYaMdwv

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Even if this works, it seems a hack-ish workaround rather than a best practice solution? Why does it even work? What are the browser vendors' statement on the issue?

Comment: I'm just a student who does web development as a hobby and this is solution is good enough for me. I just wanted to share this as a quick fix for others. As for deeper research and interviews I will leave it to others, potentially no one. I did a little research at first but I barely found anything on that topic. If your google searches are better than mine you are free to share your findings.